# How to control variable in a function from another script?

Tags: javascript, html, json, callback

I have code like this (http://jsfiddle.net/tb7E9/1/):

```
<script>
    function listEvents(json) {
        var feed = json.feed;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            //Style
            if (i == 0) {
                x = "<span style='color:red'>Style 1 </span><p>" + posttitle + "</p>";
                p = "<span style='color:red'>Style 2 </span><h4>" + posttitle + "</h4><p>";
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                y = "<p>" + posttitle + "</p>";
                g = "<h4>" + posttitle + "</h4></p>";
            }
        }
        style1 = x + y; document.write(style1);
        style2 = p + g; document.write(style2);
    }
</script>
```

The second Script:

```
<script>
    //How to style1 is actived here? 
    document.write("<script src=\"http://www.allbloggertricks.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Tutorials?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=listEvents\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

I'd like to display only style (style1 is normal text or style2 is bold text as example in jsfiddle). It means if i choose style1 for display, then style2 is disable.

How can I change code in the second script to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you try to explain in other words what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks so much like another post I saw in the past few days... homework?

Comment: It looks like the function is executed after the DOM was loaded, in which case you shouldn't use `document.write`. I have no idea though if that's related to your problem because I don't understand it.

Comment: `document.write` for test.Its not main problem. I'd like to get only style(style1 or style2) from second script. Do you have any idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: @plalx: just call only style(style1 or style2) in second script (not both as in my given jsfiddle).

Comment: @happi, Well on what conditions? Technically the *second script* is just performing the JSONP call which will be handled by the *first script* callback. You just have to change the logic of the `listEvents` callback.

Comment: @plalx: I understand. You can add function or something like that in the first script to do that. But I don't know how to do. Thanks for help

Comment: @happi, Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/tb7E9/2/

Comment: @plalx: yeah. only that. But with more style(nth style), how to apply? Not only normal and bold text? :). Thanks plalx

Comment: @plalx: ok. I can apply your guid, but I dont know how can it run? Give the answer below and i will vote your answer to best. Thanks